# set RelativeLayout background to match wallpaper image

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, setbackground

I have a relative layout on top of the screen (e.g. on top of the statusbar) and i want to have it's background image the same like the underlying system wallpaper. This is no problem by doing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WindowManager window_manager=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams window_manager_layout_params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            params.FILL_PARENT,
            100,
            params.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            params.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH|
            params.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
            params.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        window_manager_layout_params.gravity=Gravity.TOP;
        RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(this);
        WallpaperManager wpm =WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        Drawable d=wpm.getDrawable();
        rl.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        window_manager.addView(rl,window_manager_layout_params);
    }
}
```

The problem is, how can i set the background drawable of the relative layout to match exactly the part of the wallpaper behind the relative layout? (no stretching and exactly the same position).

NOTE: to get the code working, you need add permission for alert window to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

[image: example of relative layout with wallpaper background]

**Edit:** to be more clear:

it should look like this:
[image: after]

but actually it looks like this:
[image: before]

Comment: As the image suggests, wouldn't setting your relativeLayout background to `TRANSPARENT` solve the issue?

Comment: Not really, because behind the relative layout is the statusbar, i have updated the question, forgot to mention this before

Comment: @RafaelCardoso: also any other position would not guarantee to see the wallpaper if i set the backrgound to transparent if there are other windows/icons,... in the background

Comment: Please be more clear about your problem..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the background color of both `RelativeLayout` and the status bar to transparent. Then you can have another layout inside the `RelativeLayout` and put a `paddingTop` on the parent layout that has same height as the status bar.

Comment: Like i said in the question, i want the relative layout has the system wallpaper as background, at the same position. Not streched, not cropped, not scaled. Like in the example above the relative layout should be like “invisible” by displaying the wallpaper. Anything behind the relative layout, like icons or other windows or in this case any status bar text should not be visible. I dont know how to exactly match the position and size of the background to fit the wallpaper. The background always appears to be stretched

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Transparent Activity` to achieve what you asking, your `theme` should look something like this

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

you could then set a solid background color to the top bar as showing in your image then you should see only the visible part of the screen which is `transparent`.

another option is to crop the wallpaper `Bitmap` base on your top bar `height`.